# Refiners not working for custom search results web part in SharePoint Online Multi-Geo tenant

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-search-web-part, people-search, classic-experience, multi-geo

We have a SharePoint Online tenant with 5 Geo tenants. Users have their profiles in different Geo tenants. We also have 2 custom properties set in each user profile.

We mapped crawl properties for these 2 custom properties with `refinablestring101` and `refinablestring102` respectively in each Geo tenant - Search Schema. These settings were done approx. 7 days back.

We set refiners using above managed properties in our custom search page. And enabled the "Show Multi-Geo results" option in search result web part.
[image]

But still these refiners are not appearing in people search result. Any help on this would be much appreciated!

So far, we followed below reference links:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/configure-search-for-multi-geo?view=o365-worldwide
- https://sharepains.com/2016/04/19/office-365-crawling-user-profiles-in-sharepoint-online/
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/multigeo-discovery

Comment: did you make sure whether managed property is filled with value to confirm whether crawling related issue or not? You can use https://github.com/pnp/PnP-Tools/tree/master/Solutions/SharePoint.Search.QueryTool tool to identify it?

Comment: We have set values for all users together. But it shows value for couple of users and empty for rest of others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in search that it couldn't capture the changes happened in User profile property values. Due to that values were not crawled and not appearing in search results data.

The solution worked for me is:

### Set the managed property to the people index

- Sign in to the Microsoft 365 admin center.
- Click Admin, click SharePoint, and then click search in the SharePoint admin center.
- Click Manage Search Schema.
- Find and open the managed property that you mapped.
- Click Advanced Searchable Settings, and then select PeopleIdx for Full-text index.
- Click OK, and then click OK at the bottom of the page.

When you change the search schema in the people categories, the change is applied only after you update a user profile. If you have to apply the change to all user profiles, you should contact Microsoft 365 technical support.

**After 8 hours from applying the above steps, data was populated for me in search and is now working as expected.**

There are other solutions and scenarios mentioned in MSDN link: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/search/updated-results-are-not-returned-when-searching-people-properties

And also a nice explanation is provided here: https://searchexplained.com/how-to-make-sure-your-user-profiles-show-up-in-search/